# How to make an animated pill like notification in Swift (UIKit)?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

Im am trying to make an animated pill like notification that slides down from the top of the phone and then slides back up to disappear.

I am trying to make something similar to the picture below.

[image]

The issue that I am having is that the label will not animate and move with the "pill."  How might I be able to fix this issue and stick the label to the pill view?

Here is my code:

```
                                    var popupView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -80, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0))
                                popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                                popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
                                popupView.bounds = popupView.frame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy: 10.0)
                                popupView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -80, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0))
                                label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                                label.bounds = label.frame.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)
                                label.textColor = .black
                                label.text = "Here is some text"

                                popupView.addSubview(label)
                                
                                UIView.transition(with: popupView, duration: 1.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                                    window?.addSubview(popupView)
                                    popupView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0)
                                    
                                  
                                    }, completion: { _ in
                                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                                            popupView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -80, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0)
                                            popupView.bounds = parent.view.frame.insetBy(dx: 15, dy: 15)

                                            label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -80, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0)
                                        } completion: { finished in
                                            print("completed animation")
                                        }
                                        
                                    })
                            }
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand that views have their own coordinate spaces?

Answer (score 4):

Each view has its own coordinate space. A view's `frame` is its size and origin *in its superview's* coordinate space, and a view's `bounds` is its size and origin *in its own* coordinate space. Now knowing that, you'd realise that things like this clearly doesn't do what you want:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -80, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0))
// ...
popupView.addSubview(label)
```

You don't want the label to be at (0, -80) relative to the popup view! That'd be outside of the popup!

Lines such as this also don't make much sense to me:

```
popupView.bounds = popupView.frame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy: 10.0)
```

That's mixing things from two different coordinate spaces. If you want to make a view smaller by 10 points on each edge, and maintain the centre position, just change the `frame`:

```
popupView.frame = popupView.frame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy: 10.0)
```

If `label` is a subview of `popupView`, it *will* move together with `popupView` if you just move `popupView`. There is no need to move `label` separately at all, like you have done.

Fixing a few other small issues, your code becomes:

```
let popupView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -80, width: (window?.frame.size.width ?? 100), height: 75.0))
popupView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
popupView.frame = popupView.frame.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)
let label = UILabel(frame: popupView.bounds)
label.bounds = label.bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)
label.textColor = .black
label.text = "Here is some text"
popupView.addSubview(label)

UIView.transition(with: popupView, duration: 1.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    window?.addSubview(popupView)
    popupView.center.y += 160
}, completion: { _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
        popupView.center.y -= 160
    } completion: { finished in
        print("completed animation")
        // remember to remove the popup when you're done!
        popupView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any good resources or books that might help me better understand the UIKit views (with the bounds and frame)?

Comment: @Nighthawk I don’t know any books. [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) is really good at explaining basic concepts such as these. If you don’t understand that, maybe also try finding something on raywenderlich. They probably have something about this.